# Webgrid refresh with ajax in MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, webgrid

I have a Webgrid that I need to refresh when pressing a button 'Refresh'. I also have a search input.

Everything is working fine, except that everytime that I hit refresh, the pageNumber is being set back to one...

Here is my code...

**controller**

```
public ActionResult ListImporting(string searchText = "", int page = 1)
        {
            ViewBag.RowsPerPage = 2;

            searchText = searchText.Trim();
            ViewBag.searchText = searchText;
            ViewBag.page = page;

            DtoPaginatedResult<ListImportingDTO> model = listService.GetListsInProgress(page, ViewBag.RowsPerPage, searchText);

            if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                return PartialView("ListImportingGrid", model);
            else
                return View(model);

        }
```

Then I have a view *List Importing* that calls the partial...

```
<input id="refreshButton" type="button" value="Refresh" style="float:right"/>

<div id="resultList" style="margin-top:20px">
    @Html.Partial("ListImportingGrid", Model)
</div>
```

......

```
   $("#refreshButton").live("click",updateGrid);
```

And inside the partial I have the grid, and the current function

```
function updateGrid() {     
    var pageNumber = @ViewBag.page;
    console.log(pageNumber);
    $.ajax(
     { type: "GET" ,
         url: '/Admin/ListImporting/',
         data: { searchText: $("#searchBox").val(),  
         page: pageNumber
             } ,
             dataType: "html" ,
             success: function  (data){             
                 $("#resultList").html(data);
                  } 
         })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page is loaded you are hard coding the pagenumber to ViewBag.page which is always going to be equal to one on page load.

Instead what you need to do is create a hidden input in the partialview and place the javascript code in the main view.

Then when the updateGrid function is triggered look in the patial view, via javascript, and find the value that is in the hidden field for the page number.

Switch to PagedList, it's a lot easier to work with ajax, pagination, and webgrids.
https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList

Comment: I have no idea why this worked, and putting it in the script didnt..

This is the code 

<input type="hidden" id="pageNumeber" value="@ViewBag.page" />

And in the updateGrid, I just got the value via JQuery

Comment: It could be a caching issue, I always try to do my javascript in an external js file or in the main view instead of inside of partials. Glad that worked for you though. If you need more webgrid examples let me know, I'm doing some cool searching, paging, page size, and ajax webgrid driven views.

Answer (score 0):

Your pageNumber is being reset back to 1 because every time you call updateGrid you're resetting it to the ViewBag.page

in other words, the compiled razor code looks like

```
function updateGrid() {
    var pageNumber = 1;
    ....
```

So you should create pageNumber somewhere else, if you don't want it to be reset when you call updateGrid, like this

```
var pageNumber = ViewBag.page;
function updateGrid() {
     ....
```

Comment: But when i click on page 2.... in the controller it's doing ViewBag.page = 2... and returning the partial... 

After, when I click on update... why isnt ViewBag.page = 2???